# Text alignment with unknown length

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a series of vertical boxes with labels of systems in them. Next to those I need to place a set of two numbers (transaction successes and failures). It should look something like this:

```
System A    (1000, 121)
System B    (323, 142)
System C    (600, 42)
System D    (1337, 66)
```

My issue is this: I'm having a hard time figuring out how to line up the parentheses and comma for the number. I can get the width of the "System" strings using .getComputedTextWidth(), and offsetting the transaction numbers from that is simple. The numbers can range from 1 to 5 digits (at the high end, the numbers are truncated from 199,200 to 199.2k).

How can I have the parentheses and commas move to match the lengths of the numbers? These numbers are constantly changing to I can't just hard code it. I'm using D3, so the boxes and text are all in SVG format. To make it easier, I could align all of the opening parentheses with a static offset from the system names.

Added trickiness: the transaction numbers *can't* just be one string- the "successes" (first number) must be in green and the "failures" (second number) must be in red. As far as I know there isn't a way to selectively color a string.

Please let me know if I am being unclear, or you need to see a picture or an example.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you get the maximum length of the numbers across all strings and use that as the offset for the comma and parens?

Comment: So just use a standard offset for all cases? I've tried that, it looks pretty messy because you end up with a lot of empty space if the numbers are only 1 or 2 digits. That would be a last resort if I can't get this to work the way I'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tspan` elements in your text to give different words different colors and still keep them in line, rather than manually lining up a bunch of different `text` elements.

[MDN tspan page.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan)

Your dom would look like this:

```
<svg>
  <text xml:space="default" x="30" y="15">
      <tspan class="system">System</tspan>
      <tspan>A (<tspan>
      <tspan class="success">1000</tspan>
      <tspan>,<tspan>
      <tspan class="failures"> 121</tspan>
      <tspan> )<tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

This css will color the text:

```
.system{ fill: blue; }
.success{ fill: green; }
.failures{ fill: red; }
```

You can append the `tspan`s to the text one at a time in d3, like so:

```
var myText = d3.select('svg').append('text')
  .attr("x", 90)
  .attr("y", -257)

myText.append('tspan')
    .text('System')
    .classed('system', true);

myText.append('tspan')
    .text('A (');

//etc.
```

Comment: In this case, I'm using D3 to render the text elements as SVGs, so I don't think that would work. My text elements look like this:

<text x="-90" y="-257" fill="#fff">Example</text>

Comment: `tspan` elements can go inside the text. I'll add example of how to set this up in `d3`.

Comment: Woah nice! I'll give that a shot. I had no idea you could do this, if it works I owe you my firstborn son.

Comment: Actually, one more quick question: my brain might just not be functioning today, but how would I update the text in these? Depending on where the user hovers on the page, different numbers need to display. Previously I was just selecting all the text elements by classname and doing another .text() to change them. I assume its not that simple here? Right now I'm thinking that I'd have to remove and re-render them each time.

Comment: Nope! You can select the `tspan` elements and use the `text` method to change their text contents. If the `text` element has the class `textClass` and you want to change a `tspan` child of it with the class `tspanClass`, you would use `d3.select('.textClass').select('.tspanClass')`.

Comment: I managed to figure it out before I saw your response using my usual method, which I call: "try anything you can think of, it'll probably work because its javascript!". Your suggestion is exactly what I'm doing. Thanks again!